# How to make a button click dynamically when the screen loads in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I have a button Clear filters. I want the button click event to happen dynamically when the screen loads.

```
    <Button Margin="10,0" CommandParameter="Clear_Filter" Command="{Binding ButtonClicks}" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Image Source="/NextGen.Optik.UI.Presentation;component/Resources/clear_filters.png" Width="32" Height="32" Margin="0,2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Clear Filters" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
```

ViewModel:

```
      private UICommand _buttonClicks;
    public UICommand ButtonClicks
    {
        get
        {
            return _buttonClicks ?? (_buttonClicks = new UICommand(
                param => ButtonClickCommand(param),
                param => true
                ));
        }
    }
    public void ButtonClickCommand(object parameter)
    {

        switch (parameter.ToString().ToLower())
        {
            case "clear_filter":
                ClearFilter(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey! It is considered good practice to name commands in a view model in relation to their function, not UI representation, and to have separate commands for each function. In your case I would consider splitting `ButtonClicks` into smaller commands, like `ClearFilterCommand`. As for your question, I would suggest looking into `Expression.Blend.Sdk`, specifically `InvokeCommandAction` and `EventTrigger`.

Comment: One workaround would be to subscribe for the Loaded event of the Button through XAML and in OnButtonLoaded event handler call btn.Command.Execute(btn.CommandParameter);

Comment: Artem ...Used InvokeCommandAction. It is working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You didn't execute the click event or the `Button`but the `ICommand` the `Button` is binding to. To be able to do this the view model which exposes the `ICommand` should be the `DataContext` of the view. Alternatively traverse the visual tree to find the element which has the desired view model as its `DataContext`:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Button Margin="10,0" CommandParameter="Clear_Filter" Command="{Binding ButtonClicks}" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <Image Source="/NextGen.Optik.UI.Presentation;component/Resources/clear_filters.png" Width="32" Height="32" Margin="0,2" />
      <TextBlock Text="Clear Filters" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </Button>
</Window>
```

**MainWndow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += InitializeOnLoaded();
  }

  private void InitilaizeOnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    (this.DataContext as ViewModel).ButtonClickCommand("clear_filter");
  }
}
```